# How to make template deduce return type of function with variadic arguments

Tags: c++, templates, generics, variadic

Someone on stack overflow wrote an interesting way to capture a lambda or functor into your own class. I was trying to simplify it, and I think I got close but was having some trouble. Their example was:

```
// OT => Object Type
// RT => Return Type
// A ... => Arguments

template<typename OT, typename RT, typename ... A>
struct lambda_expression {
    OT _object;
    RT(OT::*_function)(A...)const; // A pointer to a member function, 
                                   // specifically the operator()

    lambda_expression(const OT & object) // Constructor
        : _object(object), 
          _function(&decltype(_object)::operator()) {} // Assigning the function pointer

    RT operator() (A ... args) const {
        return (_object.*_function)(args...);
    }
};
```

Basically this allows you to go:

```
int captureMe = 2;
auto lambda = [=](int a, int b) { return a + b + captureMe;};
lambda_expression<decltype(lambda), int, int, int>(lambda);
```

I was trying to simplify this, and thought that the pointer contained in the lambda_expression class wouldn't be needed, because you can call the function object itself, instead of calling the pointer to the operator(). So I tried this:

```
template <typename OT, typename ... Args>   // No Return type specified
struct lambdaContainer
{
    lambdaContainer(OT funcObj) : funcObj(funcObj){ }
    OT funcObj; // No pointer, just the function object.

    auto operator()(Args... args) 
    {
        return funcObj(args...); // Call the function object directly
    }
};
```

Then something like:

```
int captureMe = 2;
auto lambda = [=](int a, int b) { return a + b + captureMe; };

lambdaContainer<decltype(lambda), int, int> lam(lambda);

auto i = lam(1, 1);
// i = 4;
```

Where I wrote the line:

```
auto operator()(Args... args) 
    {
        return funcObj(args...); 
    }
```

Apparently:

```
 decltype(auto) operator()(Args... args) //works in C++14 apparently.
```

But I tried without the auto keyword and I failed miserably in doing this, I want to understand how the Args... works. I tried:

```
decltype(funObj(Args...) operator()(Args... args) // this failed
decltype(OT(Args...) operator() (Args... args) // this failed
auto operator() (Args... args) -> decltype(funcObj(Args...)) // this failed
auto operator() (Args... args) -> decltype(OT(Args...)) // this failed
```

How can I expand the Args parameter so the template can deduce the return type? Is this only possible with auto?

Comment: This might not come off correctly, but I suggest you read a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), in particular, some advanced ones. Learning C++ in torn snippets like this is incredibly hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decltype(e)` takes an *expression* `e` and evaluates to the type of that *expression*. You need to provide an *expression* that represents the invocation of your stored lambda:

```
auto operator()(Args... args) 
    -> decltype(std::declval<OT>()(std::declval<Args>()...))
```

In this case, I'm using [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) to create a "fake instance" of the objects that can be used for deduction purposes, without actually invoking any constructor.

Let's break this down even further:

```
-> decltype(
    std::declval<OT>()          // create a fake instance of `OT`
    (                           // invoke it
        std::declval<Args>()... // create a fake instance of each argument 
                                // type, expanding `Args...`
    )
)
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/E7pECKVAjdVEb6R0)

---

By the way, you should still `std::forward` the arguments in your call to `funcObj` as there might be some *rvalue references* that need to be propagated further down:

```
auto operator()(Args... args) 
{
    return funcObj(std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
}
```

Comment: That's the last thing I would have guessed. I was reading about declval and std::forward. declval I kind of get, but the other two I'm not understanding. This is interesting that you're saying that declval creates a 'fake' version of the object.

Comment: @Zebrafish: all that `declval` does is return a reference type. Since `std::declval<T>()` is a replacement for `T{}` in non-evaluated contexts, I like to think it's "creating a fake instance". But it's just returning a reference :)

Comment: @Zebrafish: what things should I clarify further?